# deselect select2 in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, jquery-select2

I'm using https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-select2/blob/master/src/select2.js to work on select2 with angularjs. There is a **button to reset select2 (i.e, set placeholder)**. On clicking button, I have to call a function from angular controller. In that function, I have to reset select2. I don't know how to do. I'm new in angularjs. So I can't understand directive. If anyone knows the solution with explanation, it will be appreciated.

Here is my code till now,

**HTML**

```
<select class="form-control" ui-select2="select2Options" id="ddlTechnology" name="ddlTechnology" ng-model="technology" ng-change="changeData('technology', technology)" ng-options="tech as tech.st_name for tech in technologies" style="width: 100%;">
    <option value=""></option>
</select>
<button ng-click="resetSearch()">Reset</button>
```

**JS**

```
$scope.technologies = [{
    $hashKey: "object:14",
    in_technology_id: 1,
    st_name: "Networking"},
    {},
    {},
    ...
];
$scope.resetSearch = function () {
    $("#ddlTechnology").select2('val', '');
}
```

Comment: Can you please provide the technologies array which you are listing it in options

Comment: @Vikash, see update please. I have added technologies array

Comment: Did you try the solution mentioned below

Answer (score 1):

The idea here is to make your ng-model empty on reset. And as per documentation ui-select2 is incompatible with `<select ng-options>`. For the best results use `<option ng-repeat>`. Please find the working plunker [Plunker - UI Select2 with Reset](https://plnkr.co/edit/fB7xIo5GGgxTknoyupCW?p=preview)

```
$scope.resetSearch = function () {
    $scope.technology = '';
}
```

But I would strongly recommend you to use https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-select as the link mentioned by you for select2 is depreceated.